# Adding Integers and Decimals in JMeter

Tags: casting, jmeter, beanshell

We're trying to use a Beanshell Sampler in JMeter to add variables of which, one is a decimal.  The code that we have is as follows (passing in five parameters, of which, the first is decimal value and the rest are integers):

```
import java.util.*;

String [] params = Parameters.split(",");

a = Double.valueOf(params[0]);
b = Double.valueOf(params[1]);
c = Double.valueOf(params[2]);
d = Double.valueOf(params[3]);
e = Double.valueOf(params[4]);

sum = a + b + c + d + e;
vars.putObject("OutOfT", sum);
```

However, this is not working and we are unable to get the OutOfT value but instead, get a  java.lang.ClassCastException error.  Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a [doubleSum](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#doubleSumsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup) function available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)

In general your code is OK so my expectation is that there is a problem with the input.

To get more informative error message you can do the following:

1. Add `debug();` directive as a very first line of your Beanshell script and look into console where you launched JMeter for the debug output
2. Other way is surrounding your Beanshell code with try/catch block like:

   ```
   try {
       // your code here
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Beanshell error", ex);
   }
   ```

   You'll see "Beanshell error" line followed by detailed stacktrace in *jmeter.log* file.

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more tips on getting to the bottom of your JMeter script problem